# How to Show p:submenu always expanded

Tags: jsf, primefaces

As the title says,  i need to show always the submenu always expanded. I've tried already with the attribute expanded="true". But this only works to show the element expanded at the beginning, but not turn off that functionality. I've also checked the API of primefaces and there is nothing about this.

```
 <p:panelMenu>
     <p:submenu expanded="true" value="submenu"> <!-- If the user clicks here the menu will expand/collapse-->
       ..
     </p:submenu>
    </p:panelMenu>
```

I know that I could do this easily with JavaScript , but that is not an option due to the client doesn't want javascript code :-(. This [example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/panelMenu.xhtml) in the primefaces showcase also has the default behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a variety of types of menus. p:menu might be the thing you are looking for.

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/menu.xhtml